# Cancel Editing during Gridview_RowEditing()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2013, postback

I want to cancel *row editing* during `RowEditing` if the current user doesn't have the necessary permissions.

This is what `RowEditing` looks like:

```
protected void GridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    string user = GetCurrentUser();
    if (user == string.Empty)
    {
        /* Show message alert */
        return;
    }
    GridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();
}
```

This cancels the *Update* and the column continues with the *Edit* link. But if I click *Edit* again, it will show this error:

> Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

I assume it has to with hiding controls before a postback is made.

So my question is, how do I avoid this?

I also tried setting `GridView.EditIndex = -1`, but I get the same results:

```
protected void GridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();
    string user = GetCurrentUser();
    if (user == string.Empty)
    {
        /* Show message alert */
        GridView.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem just now. then i just found out this is very easy fix.
Call e.Cancel = true will solve the problem

```
protected void GridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    string user = GetCurrentUser();
    if (user == string.Empty)
    {
       MsgBox.Prompt(Page, "Not authorize");
       e.Cancel = true;
       BindData();
    }
     else
    {
       GridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
       BindData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            //NewEditIndex property used to determine the index of the row being edited.  
            gvBookStoreRecords.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            gridDataBind();
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            //Finding the controls from Gridview for the row which is going to update  
            TextBox Name = gvBookStoreRecords.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Name") as TextBox;
            TextBox Birthdate = gvBookStoreRecords.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Birthdate") as TextBox;
            TextBox Gender = gvBookStoreRecords.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Gender") as TextBox;
            //Setting the EditIndex property to -1 to cancel the Edit mode in Gridview  
            gvBookStoreRecords.EditIndex = -1;
            //Call ShowData method for displaying updated data  
            gridDataBind();
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            //Setting the EditIndex property to -1 to cancel the Edit mode in Gridview  
            gvBookStoreRecords.EditIndex = -1;
            gridDataBind();
        }    
*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
    <asp:GridView ID="gvBookStoreRecords" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvBookStoreRecords_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"   

    OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <Columns>  
                    <asp:TemplateField>  
                        <ItemTemplate>  
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />  
                        </ItemTemplate>  
                        <EditItemTemplate>  
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>  
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"/>  
                        </EditItemTemplate>  
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>  
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>*
```

Comment: What is this? Can you explain your answer?

Comment: I used above C# code for editing. In edit user can update or cancel, and ASPX code for UI grid design.

Comment: If it doesn't work, then why did you post it as an answer?